# Is there a way to edit the default launch.json file that VSCode creates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, console

Whenever I make a new C# console application, VSCode creates a default launch.json file for me. Is there a way to change the default configuration of this file? (I want to change the default console from "integratedConsole" to "externalTerminal")

Comment: What you probably want to do is to create a global launch configuration. More info in the docs: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_global-launch-configuration